# How do I convert user's local time to Toronto timezone and then check dst based on Toronto time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, dst

Right now I'm using `moment` to check daylight savings time.

```
moment(date).isDST()
```

Problem is, some users live in countries with no DST so it doesn't work. I've tried converting their time to my local time

```
momentTimeZone().tz('America/Toronto').format();
```

But, I'm not sure how to then check for DST.

Comment: So to try to avoid an X/Y problem, why do you need to know if they are under DST?  What is the situation where you cannot use the UTC as a base?

Answer (score 1):

so for user living in other time zones take their time

and do this

```
var t = moment("2013-11-18").tz("America/Toronto");

moment(t).isDST()
```

use this url for their docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/